# Dictionary Keys-Repeat (List<int>) in Python#

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, duplicates

This is an assignment; I have worked over it and somewhere get stuck;

This is the input from text file:

```
    min: 1,2,3,5,6
    max: 1,2,3,5,6
    avg: 1,2,3,5,6
    p90: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
    sum: 1,2,3,5,6
    min: 1,5,6,14,24
    max: 2,3,9
    p70: 1,2,3
```

This is the required output to the text file:

```
    The min of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 1
    The max of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 6
    The avg of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 3.4
    The 90th percentile of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] is 9
    The sum of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 17
    The min of [1, 5, 6, 14, 24] is 1
    The max of [2, 3, 9] is 9
    The 70th percentile of [1, 2, 3] is 2
```

This is my work-out to the text file:

```
    The min of [1, 5, 6, 14, 24] is 1
    The max of [2, 3, 9] is 9
    The avg of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 3.4
    The p90 of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] is 9.0
    The sum of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 17
    The p70 of [1, 2, 3] is 2.1
```

Logics

1. I wrote a function to read from a file and insert the keys:values into dictionary;

Below is the dictionary

```
    OrderedDict([('min', [1, 5, 6, 14, 24]), ('max', [2, 3, 9]), ('avg', [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]), ('p90', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]), ('sum', [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]), ('p70', [1, 2, 3])])
```

2. From here I compute the required and write the results to the file
3. My question; how can I make the keys min and max duplicate in the dictionary as you can see the have been overwritten

Comment: Is there any reason you need to store the items in a dictionary - seems to me you can just read line by line, do the calculation and print the results, and that's it... you don't need to worry about duplicate keys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the keys in a dictionary are unique. That means, a dictionary can only have one entry with the key 'min'. That's why your first entry with the key 'min' gets overwritten by the second.

To solve this I would recommend to change the structure type from `Dictionary` to something else (like a nested `List`).

```
list = []
list.append(['min', [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]])
```

you will get a list of *rows*, each containing the function (like 'min') and the number array.

[More about Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)